# Getting a Maven Error even while the jar is present

Tags: java, spring, maven, neo4j, spring-boot

I am getting an error while running mvn clean install. The error is as below

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project gs-accessing-data-neo4j: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project gs-accessing-data-neo4j: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl. java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:repackage failed: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default BuildPluginManager.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:357)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:325)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:83)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached inthe local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:200)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
    ... 27 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

I have checked the jar files for org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.7.RELEASE as well as aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0.
There is a valid jar at the remote repository as well as my local repository.
Unable to figure out why such an error is cropping up.

My pom.xml is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-accessing-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j</id>
            <name>Neo4j</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

The settings.xml for my proxy settings is as below

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository/>
    <interactiveMode/>
    <usePluginRegistry/>
    <offline/>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <servers/>
    <mirrors/>
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>proxyurl</host>
            <port>8080</port>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
            <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
    <profiles/>
    <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Comment: I don't know about why but - would removing the file `_maven.repositories` from local repository help? Or simply removing the local repo entirely?

Comment: Where did you notice the file _maven.repositories. I don't have any such file.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the mentioned artifact directories (spring-core and aopalliance) from your local m2 cache and trying again? To rule out the case that this is because of previous failures to download the artifacts.

Comment: Try running `mvn -U clean install`.

Comment: Tried doing that. But still get the same error.

Comment: Looks like some plugin tried to shell out to 'cmd' - try with the -X (debug) and / or -e (show stack traces) switches to see more detail

Comment: Hi Bro ,Are you using Eclipse or Any Other IDE ?

Comment: I tried with -e and -X options. But still could not figure out the cause of the error.

Comment: No, I am not using any IDE.

Comment: Please include the console output when you run with the -X option, from what you've shown it's impossible to answer your question

Comment: Please add the `repositories` section from your settings.xml file - it looks like something could be wrong there

Comment: I have added the complete settings.xml file.

Comment: Have you obfuscated the proxy settings?  What you've shown looks like you have but if not then those proxy settings look like they stop you connecting

Comment: No, I have deliberately obfuscated the proxy settings. The proxy url, username and password contain valid data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88111/discussion-between-rammohan-and-nick-holt).